# Why is noise is considered to be a "Common Mode Signal"?

Tags: noise, cmrr

I learnt that the magnetic interference due to the Earth causes noise in the cable but I wonder why this is considered to be a 'Common Mode Signal' and why differential amplifiers are used to eliminate it?

Comment: The earth's magnetic field is static so can induce no noise. Solar flares can cause magnetic interference and these can induce voltages in cables but if signalling is differential and links are two wire differential impedance matched, then the induced voltage is the same in both wires and is common mode hence removed with a differential amplifier.

Comment: @Andyaka The earth magnetic field is static, but the system might be moving and vibrating, so theoretically the noise can be induced by Earth magnetic field.

Comment: I've never been very keen on the term "common mode noise". It makes it sound like something far more complicated than it is and I believe actually confuses people to think it means more than it does. Simply "Common Noise" is sufficient, meaning it is common, or the same, on both or all wires.

Comment: @Andy aka Ok I understood but my question also is that why noises are considered to as a "common mode signal" ?

Comment: @DhirajDhakal Because if a signal is transferred using two wires (signal and return, or just a differential signal), the *ambient* noise is affecting *both* wires in the similar way, I.e. is *common* for both wires.

Comment: @EugeneSh. : ok thanks, i have one more question, perhaps it may be naive but i find its answer nowhere; can two wires have noises in opposite phases and thereby get amplified twice instead, due to the differential amplifier?

Comment: These won't be common mode and likely to come out from elsewhere, probably some electronics.

Comment: @DhirajDhakal two wires having noise in opposite phase is quite unlikely unless you are purposely introducing them (Like keeping two wires physically sperate under different conditions hence different noise on different lines), and twisted wires solve this problem. And in most(almost all) of practical applications both the wires will be together.

Comment: Please go through this as well https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79752/what-is-common-mode-noise?rq=1

Comment: "can two wires have noises in opposite phases" the common-ness can vary based on the geometry of the wires and source direction and frequency of the noise. That's why we use twisted pairs, so that those effects are nullified to a great extent.

Comment: @Trevor "common noise" - might this be confused with some pre-cursor to a working-class-uprising or maybe what a football crowd sounds like or, maybe just some forms of modern music?

Comment: lol @Andyaka I was thinking the same thing when I wrote my comment... great minds ;)

Comment: The earth magnetic field is not totally static, it is changing slowly, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geomagnetic_storm . Well, very slowly from an electronic viewpoint. There was a black out in Quebec https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March_1989_geomagnetic_storm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, this picture below hopefully explains why a differential signalling receiver will cancel out interference (or noise) on both wires: -

[image]

It's a simple case of A minus B i.e. the noise/interference gets cancelled but the wanted signal gets left intact.

Secondly, when an interference source is some distance away from the two-wire cable, it largely inflicts noise equally onto both conductors hence the noise is called "common-mode". When a noise source is much closer to one wire than the other there will be a noticibly differential noise signal and this isn't so easily dealt with by a receiving differential amplifier.

So, you have common-mode noise and differential noise and to make the incident noise only (mainly) have common-mode effects you need to do several of the things below: -

- Use matched impedances to ground so that any influence from noise sees equal impedances to ground thus, one wire does not naturally receive a larger noise signal than the other.
- Keep the noise source as far from the cable as possible
- Use differentail signalling to improve signal level amplitude (reduce SNR)
- Use twisted pair so that magnetic noise induces the same voltage on both wires. This also helps a bit with electric field interference.
- Use a screen so that electric fields couple to the screen and, due to internal capacitances, couple equally to both wires.
- Use a receiver that can deal linearly with signal and superimposed noise (transformers are good for this).

Answer (score 7):

Noise will affect both the lines in similar way hence by using a differential amplifier you eliminate the signal which is common to both the input (which is noise).

[image]

Thats the reason you will find many op-amps witll have very high CMRR value which is common mode rejection ratio.

Comment: You can learn more over here https://youtu.be/BFLZm4LbzQU