# What is Common Mode Noise

Tags: noise, common-mode

I have read [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79752/what-is-common-mode-noise) before asking this question. I understand somewhat, but I couldn't get clarity. Can someone help me understand the difference between common mode noise and differential mode noise with some pictures and circuits, please.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between **differential mode** and **common mode** signals? If not start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common-mode_signal and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/325831/why-is-noise-is-considered-to-be-a-common-mode-signal Then consider that **noise** behaves similar to a **signal** with the difference that noise is usually unpredictable and unwanted.

Comment: Did you understand the analogy of the battery bouncing around on a spring representing common mode noise (my very short answer)?

Comment: Read this: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470508510